# Sketch- Pad Code Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys i am learning Web development and i am complete rookie.when i enter the mouse in the blocks it should change color but it seems to be not changing color and i am not able to figure out why,may be due to lack of knowledge.

sorry for my bad English.

JS:

```js
var squareGrid = function() {
  $('#gridContainer').html("");

  var input = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 100.");
  var color = prompt("Enter a  Color i.e red,blue,black,yellow");
  var clr = color.toLowerCase();

  var squareSize = $('#gridContainer').width() / input - 2;

  for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= input; j++) {
      $('#gridContainer').append('<div class="square"></div>');
    };
  }
  $('.square').css('width', squareSize);
  $('.square').css('height', squareSize);

  $('.square').mouseenter(function() {
    if (clr === black) {
      $(this).addClass('black');
    } else if (clr === red) {
      $(this).addClass('red');
    } else if (clr === blue) {
      $(this).addClass('blue');
    } else if (clr === yellow) {
      $(this).addClass('yellow');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
CSS:

#buttonContainer {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}
#gridContainer {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}
.square {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.new_row {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sketch-Pad</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <button id="start" onclick="squareGrid()">Start!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="gridContainer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to put quotes around the strings for your color. E.g. `(clr === black)` should be `(clr === "black")`

Comment: Alternatively, you could remove the `if` stuff entirely and just do `$(this).addClass(clr)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The value of your **clr** variable is a string so when comparing it to a value (IE black), you need to wrap that value in quotation marks.

```js
$('.square').mouseenter(function() {
    if (clr === "black") {
      $(this).addClass('black');
    } else if (clr === "red") {
      $(this).addClass('red');
    } else if (clr === "blue") {
      $(this).addClass('blue');
    } else if (clr === "yellow") {
      $(this).addClass('yellow');
    }
  });
```

Comment: I already noted this in a comment. Instead of trying to farm rep from the typos in this question, please vote to close it as off-topic instead.

Comment: Thnx Guys that was a stupid mistake made by me :( ;
Hope I will not repeat the same mistake again.

Comment: @j08691 I blew right past your comment, sorry. That said, the question meets most of the criteria for SO's definition of a 'Good Question' and likewise for my answer. I did not perceive it as a typo but rather a misunderstanding of string variables (as evidenced by my answer).  Are their guidelines that I'm not aware of that merit a down vote on my answer? (serious question)